# Why is the new series called 2014?

Tags: fairy-tail

So I noticed that the new season of [fairy-tail](/questions/tagged/fairy-tail) came out as Fairy Tail (2014), and wondered why they decided to name it like this.

I know a similar name has been used for the remake of [hunter-x-hunter](/questions/tagged/hunter-x-hunter) and I have been told they named it (2011) here as it is a remake in higher quality. But I dont see any quality changes, and neither is it a remake of the original Fairy Tail. But rather a continuation on the story told.

So why was the new Fairy Tail Season called Fairy Tail (2014) ?

Comment: To be perfectly honest I actually thought the arcs were the seasons in fairy tail. I may have been wrong.

Comment: @MiharuDante Might have formulated it incorrectly, but do not know how to state it in another way. If you know a better way of naming it feel free to edit it.

Comment: There are quality changes btw: actual flames get produced than just CG radiant flame covers; no more magic circles before EVERYTHING (closer to the manga); and there's sharper detail on character artwork. Unfortunately -- and amazingly, they have done NOTHING about the fluidity of the animation beyond those necessary touchups so you still get that cheesy post-attack pose when someone does something than see anyone actually execute.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since it is conventional for English-language anime-listing sites (e.g. MAL) to treat a break in airing as marking the end of one series and the start of another, you need some way to differentiate between the series that ended before the break and the one that started after.

In the case of something like *Naruto*, the second part had a different title ("Shippuuden"), which makes the task of naming the new season easy (i.e. just call it what it is). Since *Fairy Tail* was called "Fairy Tail" both before and after the break in airing, you need some way to distinguish between the two series on the anime-listing sites. Using the year in which the series started airing is as good a way as any.

I should emphasize that this is purely an artefact of the way that sites like MAL name series. As far as the people producing *Fairy Tail* are concerned, the episodes that started airing this month are part of the same series as the episodes that aired from 2009-2013. If, for example, you consult [the timetable for TV Tokyo](http://www.tv-tokyo.co.jp/index/timetable/), which airs *Fairy Tail*, you will see that this week's episode is listed as:

> ＦＡＩＲＹ ＴＡＩＬ ～フェアリーテイル～「妖精軍師」

This is the same title that was used for the show before the break in airing (the last bit is the episode title "Yousei Gunshi", something like "Fairy Tactician").

Comment: I thought it was called Fairy Tail S2...Actually I know when  search for it I need to search for fairy tail s2